# When to use "electricity" and when to use "power"?

Tags: word-usage

Many non-native English speakers, especially from Asia, often say "`There is no electricity at home`".

But seem that the native English speakers will say "`There is no power at home`".

so, When to use "electricity" and when to use "power"?

Comment: Real Example:  "During the storm, we were without power for 6 days.  We're on a well, so when we don't have electricity, we don't have water."  Thus, I suggest that you say "power" as the general term, and say "electricity" when you mean that you need voltage and current to do a specific thing -- in this example, run the well's pump.  But it doesn't really matter; you will be understood either way.

Comment: most native English speakers I met use "power" in the case we only talk about electricity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two words are not synonymous although they may sometimes appear to be so. It is a function of context. As a native speaker, I say we have no power at home when it is clear from the domestic context that we have no electricity. If I were in a car and said we have no power, I would mean we have no working engine or transmission. If in a ship driven by steam turbine, I would mean we have no steam or no transmission, unless I were referring to the electricity supply points, in which case I would mean we have no elecricity.

Comment: "power: energy that is produced by mechanical, electrical, or other means and used to operate a device." So if you say our car has no power  --> our car has no energy produced by engine?

Comment: Yes, a car whose engine has no power produces no energy. However, be aware that, in physics, there is a distinction between the two words. Power is the rate at which energy is delivered. For example, energy is measured in Joules; power is Joules per second, otherwise known as Watts. A car engine of power one hundred kilowatts would deliver one hundred thousand Joules of energy per second.